# How do i reference in flask HTML templates stored in a seperate container?

Tags: docker, flask, jinja2

I am building a website using docker.

The main site will be built in flask / python and placed into one container.

However, for the blog I'm considering building it in WordPress/PHP and placing it into another container.

So I'm not replicating the CSS/JS files/HTML templates that both sites will require, is it possible to place these into their own container, with both the other containers referencing them?

[image]

If so, how would I reference these files in flask? For e.g. how might the 'include' code below be modified so it references navbar.html that is stored in a different container?

```
{% extends 'template.html' %}
{% block nav %}
{% include 'navbar.html' %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To configure multiple Docker containers to share common files you should take a look at Docker volumes, particularly at using [read-only volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#use-a-read-only-volume):

> Remember that multiple containers can mount the same volume, and it can be mounted read-write for some of them and read-only for others, at the same time.

The documentation provides an example invocation:

```
$ docker run -d \
  --name=nginxtest \
  --mount source=nginx-vol,destination=/usr/share/nginx/html,readonly \
  nginx:latest
```

This mounts the volume `nginx-vol` to `/usr/share/nginx/html` and marks it read-only.

To get back to your particular use case: You could create a Docker volume, store your templates in there and mount it to the container running your Flask app at `/opt/project/app/templates` (assuming your project is stored in `/opt/project` and stores its templates in `app/templates`; you will have to adjust the paths to your own setup).

Comment: Volumes have some significant problems: they completely ignore updates in the underlying images, and they don't translate well to cluster environments like Kubernetes.